# Which term would be appropriate to say "next" on a button within a sequence of pages?

Tags: português-brasileiro

I have a digital wizard-like survey that has multiple pages with buttons "previous", "save" and "next" on it.

What term would sound more natural to label the button "Next", to prompt a user to proceed to the next page?

(1) Siguiente or (2) Seguinte?

[image: a screenshot of 3 previous-save-next buttons]

Comment: "(1) Siguiente" Is  not in Portuguese, so that's not even an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PT-BR, you could use:

- Back -> Anterior
- Back -> Voltar
- Next -> Próximo
- Next -> Continuar
- Save -> Salvar

Comment: Cool, thank you! What about pt-PT are terms similar?

Comment: @McV The answer from CIMend refers to pt-PT.

Comment: I don't think that CIMend's answer is pt-PT. (If it is, it should say so! The question is asking for pt-BR.) In pt-PT installation wizards, I think that the idiomatic word for "next" is "seguinte".

Comment: @McV the literal translation "salvar" is not used in pt-PT. We use _guardar_ (or, more uncommonly, _gravar_).

Answer (score 3):

In Portuguese, you could use, like in the example shown in the image below:

- Back -> Anterior
- Next -> Continuar
- Save -> Guardar

[image: an example installer, showing the next-save-previous buttons in Portuguese]

Comment: Continuar também é utilizado e é equivalente a próximo

Comment: Your answer offers two options for "next". It should explain their differences.

Comment: Continuar is also plausible imho.